# Ember Expected property shorthand object-shorthand

Tags: ember.js, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have an action in one of my Ember controllers where I am making a call to my backend, and ESLint is giving me an error

`Ember Expected property shorthand  object-shorthand`

in the AJAX data for 'preserve': preserve

I'm new to Ember, and somewhat new to ES6 syntax, so I'm not entirely sure how this chunk of code could be made any more 'shorthand'.

Controller

```
merge(preserve) {
      let experienceIdList = [];

      // To-Do Make this a computed property
      get(this, 'model.experiences').forEach(function(experience) {
        experienceIdList.pushObject(experience.id);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: `${config.EmberENV.API_HOST}/api/v0.1/experiences/merge/`,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'experience_ids': experienceIdList,
          'name': get(this, 'model.newExperience.name'),
          'preserve': preserve,
          'moduleExperience': get(this, 'moduleExperience')
        }
      }).then(() => {
        this.transitionToRoute('authenticated.experiences');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        this.set('errorMessage', error.error || error);
      });
    }
```

Comment: just a guess: change `catch(function(error) {` to  `catch(error => {`

Comment: and/or `.forEach(function(experience) {` to `.forEach(experience => {`

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that wasn't it : (

Comment: does the err msg give you a line?

Comment: Yeah, sorry probably should've mentioned that, it the line in data for 'preserve': preserve

Comment: try changing `'preserve': preserve,` to `preserve,` (no `'`, no `:`). Following [this doc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand)

Comment: That was it ! Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [ESLint documentation on object-shorthand](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand) change

```
'preserve': preserve,
```

to

```
 preserve,
```

so the full object declaration of `data` should be:

```
 data: {
      'experience_ids': experienceIdList,
      'name': get(this, 'model.newExperience.name'),
      preserve,
      'moduleExperience': get(this, 'moduleExperience')
}
```

Note, that you can change this behavior in the es-lint options which you will find in this file: `.eslintrc.js` (in ember-root)